# How do you add together confidence intervals when adding estimates together?

Tags: confidence-interval

I struggle with statistics so this might be a stupid questions but can you explain to me in a 'for dummies' fashion if I can add together two estimates with confidence intervals and how to calculate the confidence interval.

For example we have two areas right beside each other and an population estimate for each area with a 95% CI, and what to give a population estimate for both areas together.

Comment: Do you only have the two confidence intervals, or also other information, like sample sizes, ...